# XSLT variable attribute-set

Tags: xslt

I have a question related to xsl:use-attribute-sets.
I want to have elements, which have variable attribute-sets. 
e.g:

```
<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="$variable">
</block>
```

This approach is not working.
I tried to make a workaround and came to the conclusion, that it is possible to add the attributes of the attribute-set through a for-each.
e.g:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:variable name="attributeSets" select="document('./document.xsl')//xsl:attribute-set"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$attributeSets[@name=$attributeSetName]/xsl:attribute">
        <xsl:attribute name="@name" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:block>
```

This approach allows me to add the attributes to the element. The problem is, that if an attribute contains a xsl element like choose, it is not handled properly.

Is it possible to evaluate xslt code like this?

The attribute-set would look like this:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="test">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="condition">40pt</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>20pt</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">right</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

The output is:

```
<fo:block font-size="40pt20pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="right"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question related to xsl:use-attribute-sets. I want to have
>   elements, which have variable attribute-sets. [...]
>   This approach is not working.

It wouldn't.  Variable references are only meaningful in expressions.  The values of some XSL attributes are defined to be interpreted as expressions, and expressions can occur inside attribute values that are defined to be attribute-value templates, but no use of `xsl:use-attribute-sets` attributes is defined to fall into either of those categories.

> I tried to make a workaround and came to the conclusion, that it is
>   possible to add the attributes of the attribute-set through a
>   for-each. e.g:
>
> ```
> <fo:block>
>     <xsl:variable name="attributeSets" select="document('./document.xsl')//xsl:attribute-set"/>
>     <xsl:for-each select="$attributeSets[@name=$attributeSetName]/xsl:attribute">
>         <xsl:attribute name="@name" select="."/>
>     </xsl:for-each>
> </fo:block>
> ```
>
> This approach allows me to add the attributes to the element.

You are reading the stylesheet document as an additional input document, and transforming it to emit <xsl:attribute> elements into the result tree.  It's simultaneously clever and horrifying.

> The
>   problem is, that if an attribute contains a xsl element like choose,
>   it is not handled properly.

Where by "properly" I guess you mean the way that the attribute declaration would be handled if the attribute set were designated (explicitly) by name in an `xsl:use-attribute-sets` attribute.  Indeed, it wouldn't be handled that way.  You are using the stylesheet as an additional input document.  This is fine, in the sense that XSL is expressed in XML, but input documents have no XSL semantics.

> Is it possible to evaluate xslt code like this?

XSL has mechanisms for obtaining parts of the stylesheet from external files, but not for processing random node sets according to XSL semantics.  Perhaps there is an implementation which provides such a feature as an extension, but I have no specific knowledge of one.

There are other workarounds than the one you discovered, some of which should provide the XSLT semantics you want.  For example:

- use modes or template names instead of computed variable values to select combinations of attribute sets:

  ```
  <xsl:template name="foo-bar-block">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="foo bar"/>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

You'll still not be able to compute template names or modes dynamically, but you can choose dynamically which template(s) to call or apply.

- Use templates *instead of* attribute sets.  Optionally, create one or more master attribute templates that choose which pseudo-attribute-set templates to use in any given case:

  ```
  <xsl:template name="variable-size-attributes">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="condition">40pt</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>20pt</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="font-style-attributes">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">right</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <fo:block>
      <!-- possibly a conditional here ... -->
      <xsl:call-template name="variable-size-attributes"/>
      <!-- possibly a conditional here ... -->
      <xsl:call-template name="font-style-attributes"/>
    </fo:block>
    <!-- or -->
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:call-template name="choose-what-attribute-sets-apply"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Your second approach is interesting. Template names have to be 'QNames' too though. So it is not really helping me, because there is the same problem (I can not call templates by variable names). In case with the templates I have to make a giant choose which one to apply. That is what I am doing with the attribute sets right now. At least it shortens the code a bit. :)
I guess there is no real workaround then, but thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have some more flexibility, you could do something like this:

```xml
<xsl:attribute-set name="my-attribute-set">
  <xsl:attribute
      name="font-family"
      select="custom:getMyFont(ancestor::*[@xml:lang][1]/@xml:lang)"/>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

So, you could look at the XML tree and call a function.